# Where should I implement RxJavaPlugins.onError?

Tags: android, rx-java

I have android application. I have UnderivableException and I want to implement RxJavaPlugins.onError. I read some artical about it. But no one of this artical doesn't show where should I implement this.

Comment: Are you sure you mean ```RxJavaPlugins.onError``` and not ```RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler``` ? Do you want to propagate an error or handle it?

Comment: Sorry, I did mistake. I mean RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler

Comment: I found answer. I need to implement RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler on Application class

Comment: I added an answer yesterday, but deleted it cause I wasn't sure if this was what you were looking for. As I was correct, please see my answer - usually you shouldn't have to implement the errorHandler.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `UnderivableException` really something you want to handle? This one usually means that you called `onError` after you have already disposed the observable. Maybe try calling `tryOnError` instead or just checking if observable has been disposed?

If you really have to handle this `UnderivableException`, you need to answer the question, what do you really want to do in this situation? Just prevent your app from crashing, or doing something more? For this first case, usually setting it in your `Application` class is enough, but if you want to do something more, you can set it in your activity or fragment, just remember to clear it before it's destroyed, to avoid leaks.